# Why is the rudder of a ship shaped like a wing?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, drag, flow

I don't understand why lift gives an advantage, it could be working the same

[image] even if it was just flat.

Comment: When you use it for steering, the wing-like shape improves the effect reducing the pressure coming from the side opposite to the direction you are taking. It is basically the same principle of wings (the shape reduces the pressure from above the wing). You manage to steer with less angular displacement of the rudder

Comment: Just to clarify: you do realize that "lift" for the rudder is in the sideways direction for the hull, don't you?

Comment: Flat wings on airplanes would also work, but not very well, because flow would separate from the surface at the leading edge, causing a stall at low angles of incidence with the flow. When that happens, lift decreases while drag increases. To get the best lift/drag ratio the flow has to follow the surface to the trailing edge.

Comment: @ Mike Dunlavey What you say is usually true, except at very low Reynolds numbers (<50,000 or so). The flat wing is actually better on very small models (& insects of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wing is an object which is designed to generate lift while keeping drag low.  That's exactly what you want from a rudder: lift from the rudder turns the ship, while drag from it means you need to burn more fuel.